# Inner Join in Access Query not working

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

Here are DB tables

**GroupsUsers**

```
GroupID   -  UserID
--------------------
00001     - user1
00002     - user1
00003     - user2
```

**Groups**

```
GroupID   -  GroupName   -  Locked   - Deleted
---------------------------------------------
00001     - gruop1       -  True     - False
00002     - gruop2       -  False       - False
00003     - gruop3       -  False       - False
```

I am getting UserIds for a specific group in query given below from GroupsUsers Table, but I also want to check if the group ID in where clause is `locked=true` or `delete=true` in Groups table then it should not be selected in result set.

Here is what I have tried yet

```
SELECT DISTINCT GU.UserId From 
GroupsUsers AS GU
 INNER JOIN Groups AS G
 ON GU.GroupID = G.GroupId
WHERE  (((G.GroupId)=00001)) AND (((G.Locked)=False)) OR (((G.Deleted)=False));
```

But this query return me all the users

**I just want to get users of a specific group if its not locked or deleted**

Comment: Please post your aspected and effective result

Comment: Your query would yield no results. Your `GroupId='00001'` is selecting the **only** record you **don't** want to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you have is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GU.UserId 
From GroupsUsers AS GU INNER JOIN Groups AS G ON GU.GroupID = G.GroupId
WHERE  (((G.GroupId)=00001)) AND (((G.Locked)=False)) OR (((G.Deleted)=False));
```

What this says is: "SELECT UserID from GroupsUsers WHERE the group id is 00001 and EITHER Locked or Deleted is false.

But in your question you've said "to check if the group ID in where clause is locked=true or delete=true in Groups table then it should not be selected in result set."

So if it is not to be selected if locked = true, or if deleted is true, then when you are testing the opposite state in your query, (ie testing against false) you need to use AND instead of OR:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GU.UserId 
From GroupsUsers AS GU INNER JOIN Groups AS G ON GU.GroupID = G.GroupId
WHERE  (((G.GroupId)=00001)) AND (((G.Locked)=False)) AND (((G.Deleted)=False));
```

PS: Access's query generator puts in loads of brackets into the where clause, but they for the most part, they arent required, and the query is a lot easier to read and understand if you get rid of them. Also if you ever need to write queries to interact with multiple types of backend databases, it will be useful to test against 0 instead of false:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GU.UserId 
From GroupsUsers AS GU INNER JOIN Groups AS G ON GU.GroupID = G.GroupId
WHERE G.GroupId = 00001 AND G.Locked = 0 AND G.Deleted = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not returning results because you're excluding the rest of the records in your `WHERE` clause.

Looking at your data: Filtering on GroupId = '0001' only gives us the first record between the two tables. The result set without the `WHERE` clause would look like

```
  UserId  GroupId                            Locked  Delete
 ----------------     {Extended Result}    ----------------
  user1    0001                               Yes      No
```

Let's add the `WHERE` clause in there:

`If a GroupId has "yes" for either Locked or Delete, don't select it"`

Well there goes the only row you selected.

If you take out the `GroupId` in the `WHERE` clause, you'll find the results you are (I think?) looking for.

```
userId
-------
user1   <- This is the second user1 in the GroupsUser's table
user2
```

This would yield results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GroupsUsers.userID,
FROM GroupsUsers
 INNER JOIN Groups ON GroupsUsers .ID = Groups.ID
WHERE (((Groups.Locked)=No)) OR (((Groups.Delete)=No));
```

If you want to check for a specific `GroupId`, and you're using *this* query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GU.UserId 
From GroupsUsers AS GU 
INNER JOIN Groups AS G 
ON GU.GroupID = G.GroupId 
WHERE (((G.Locked)=False)) 
    OR (((G.Deleted)=False)) AND (((G.GroupId)=00001));
```

You're only filtering your results based on 75% of the conditions you want. Your query is giving you the `UserId` where Locked is false OR Deleted is false when the `GroupId = 00001`. You need to apply the `GroupId` condition to both aspects of the `WHERE` clause.

`WHERE (G.Locked = False AND G.GroupId = 0001)
 OR (G.Deleted = False AND G.GroupId = 00001)`

Comment: this solution works but I Also want to check the locked and deleted status of a specific Group ID Here is the current Query
SELECT DISTINCT GU.UserId From 
GroupsUsers AS GU
 INNER JOIN Groups AS G
 ON GU.GroupID = G.GroupId
WHERE (((G.Locked)=False)) OR (((G.Deleted)=False)) AND (((G.GroupId)=00001));
But it gives me all users of the groups which are not locked or deleted...I want to check against only 1 group

Comment: Your GroupId criteria needs to be in both conditions in your WHERE clause...WHERE G.groupid = 00001 and g.locked = false OR g.groupid = 00001 AND G.deleted = false.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
and Locked='no' and Delete='no'
```

at  the end of your query

```
SELECT DISTINCT GU.UserId From 
GroupsUsers AS GU
 INNER JOIN Groups AS G
 ON GU.GroupID = G.GroupId
 WHERE GroupId='00001' and Locked='no' and Delete='no'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to return a specific group when its `Locked` status is true and you do not want to return it when its `Deleted` status is true, it means you want to return it when *both* values are `False`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  GU.UserId
FROM
  GroupsUsers AS GU
INNER JOIN
  Groups AS G ON GU.GroupID = G.GroupId
WHERE G.GroupId=00001
  AND G.Locked=False
  AND G.Deleted=False
;
```